# Adding a spark particle sprite inside a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller, scenekit

I created an `.sks` particle emitter based on the `spark` template.
My app is a normal app (not a game). When a user clicks a button, I have a new View controller that shows modally `over fullscreen` so that I can blur the background.

In this modal, I created a `view` and gave it a class of `SCNView` see image below:

[image]

How can I load the particle `.sks` file to do the animation on that viewController on the `Particles` view?

**Update**
How to load a SceneKit particle systems in view controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by @mnuages, you can use `.scnp` file instead of `.sks`, which is a SceneKit Particle System.

So the steps are:

1. Create a SceneKit Particle System, I called it `ConfettiSceneKitParticleSystem.scnp`
2. Then in your art-board, select the view and select the class `SCNView` for it like in the printscreen of the question
3. In your `UIViewController`:

   `class SomeVC: UIViewController {`

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var particles: SCNView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let scene = SCNScene()        
       let particlesNode = SCNNode()
       let particleSystem = SCNParticleSystem(named: "ConfettiSceneKitParticleSystem", inDirectory: "")
       particlesNode.addParticleSystem(particleSystem!)
       scene.rootNode.addChildNode(particlesNode)
       particles.scene = scene
   }
   ```

   `}`

Et Voila...you have you animation :)

Comment: Very helpful post! But Apple did remove **scnp** files. Any workarounds with **sks** files?

Answer (score 3):

`.sks` files are SpriteKit particle systems. You can also create SceneKit particle systems in Xcode, they are `.scnp` files.

A `.scnp` file is basically an archived `SCNParticleSystem` that you can load with `NSKeyedUnarchiver` and add to your scene using `-addParticleSystem:withTransform:`.

Comment: Any chance you can explain in more details please? This is my first time using Scenekits/spriteKits...still lost and confused.

Comment: Ok, I created a `.scnp`, how do you load it into a `SCNView` in my view controller?

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to create a SpriteKit Particle File (which is what you did). You can add it to your main view in your UIViewController.

Add this somewhere:

```
extension SKView {
 convenience init(withEmitter name: String) {
  self.init()

  self.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
  backgroundColor = .clear

  let scene = SKScene(size: self.frame.size)
  scene.backgroundColor = .clear

  guard let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: name + ".sks") else { return }
  emitter.name = name
  emitter.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 2)

  scene.addChild(emitter)
  presentScene(scene)
 }
}
```

To use:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

  view.addSubview(SKView(withEmitter: "ParticleFileName"))

}
```