# Sprite Particle System animation in viewController

Tags: macos, animation, scenekit, particle-system

I create a macOS single window application and add a Sprite Particle System file with template `Stars`. and the visual effect just like this:
[image]

And I want to add it to my viewController, as the guide of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32848302/1096059), I got the result like this, and it was not which I desired:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scene = SCNScene()
        let particlesNode = SCNNode()
        let particleSystem = SCNParticleSystem(named: "Welcome", inDirectory: "")
        particlesNode.addParticleSystem(particleSystem!)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(particlesNode)
        skView.backgroundColor = .black
        skView.scene = scene
    }
```

[image]

So, I'm wondering what's wrong and what should I do?

Here is the demo repo: [Link Here](https://gitlab.com/hamguy/StarAnimationDemo)

The particle system itself is the standard "star" SceneKit particle system available in Xcode, with no changes.

Comment: Can you post your class/object information? Did you inherit `SK/SCNView`? Override `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @Fluidity Sorry for the late reply. I just create a new demo and upload it to my gitlab repo:[link here](https://gitlab.com/hamguy/StarAnimationDemo).

Answer (score 1):

Well I made a little progress. If I swivel the camera around 180 degrees, I can see the stars receding, so we can tell that the particle system is running ok. In the default orientation, though, all I saw was blinking lights. So I think the particles are being generated with a Z position of 0, the same as the camera's.

If I move the system's node away from the camera

```
    particlesNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -20)
```

I still just see blinking lights. But if I click on the SCNView, the animation works correctly. I see stars coming at me.

I don't understand why I have to click the view to get it to work right. I tried `isPlaying = true` but that made no difference.

Comment: I moved the node away from the camera after the particle system add to the node, but just see blinking lights once the application start, clicked the view but see nothing. I'm just confused maybe I had misunderstood your answer.[new commit here](https://gitlab.com/hamguy/StarAnimationDemo/commit/3572d25d4767fa74603aba40e915b8608dcd8008)

Comment: File a Radar on this, please. The behavior is not correct, and appears to be different on our respective machines (I'm testing with Xcode 8.1, OS X 10.11.6).

Comment: File a Radar? I'm so sorry but I can not get it. I'm testing with Xcode 8.1 & macOS sierra 10.12. Would you mind to share your demo?

Comment: @HamGuy a 'radar' is the filing of a bug report to Apple. Apple has one of the most tedious, annoying and infuriating bug reporting systems known to man. You will want to reach through the screen and wring the neck of the people responsible for the 'design' of this: https://bugreport.apple.com/